# Calcultaing function limit of a limit sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

How do I even start?

$$\lim_{x \to 1^+} \lim_{n \to \infty}{x^n \over x^n + 7}$$

I see that it should be $1$ but how do i prove it?

Comment: Do you know behaviour of $x^n$ as $n$ becomes large?

Comment: $\dfrac{x^n}{x^n+7}=1-\dfrac{7}{x^n+7}$, the latter $\searrow 0$ @user3697301

Comment: Do you also see that $\lim\limits_{x\to1^-}$ is $0$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a double limit and can be solved in a two step process:

1. For an arbitrary $x>1$, calculate $$f(x) = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^n}{x^n + 7}$$
   You can use standard tricks to calculate this limit. You can even set $x=2, x=3$ first just to get an idea about how to calculate the limit in general.
2. Calculate $$\lim_{x\to 1^+} f(x)$$

Comment: @5xum The problem is that the OP means to discuss it for $x>1$...

Comment: @Martigan Yeah, sorry. Fixed it now.

Answer (score 2):

As $x>1\implies\lim_{n\to\infty}x^n\to\infty$

Now for $x>0,$  $$\dfrac{x^n}{7+x^n}=\dfrac1{1+7/x^n}$$